# Example from three.js but how to implement using SceneKit?

Tags: ios, scenekit

Example of goal:

[image]

I see three.js has this example.

It's simply a 3D Cube with many Spheres on its surface.

**How can I do something like this using SceneKit?**

Answer (score 3):

You could use an array of points, on planes, and place spheres at those locations.

Each plane divide by 10 in both directions (X and Y) and then make six of these planes and rotate them into the cube face positions.

I think performance is probably going to suck, though. This is a lot of polygons, for each of these spheres. Let's imagine each sphere has 200 tris. That's 100x 6x 200 = 1.2 million triangles.

Probably better to use circular textures on quads, placed facing the camera, at each of these 600 points. Then it's only 1200 triangles.

---

**Cheats way to do this:**

Create a SCNBox with the number of vertices desired in x, y & z axis.

Then use it as a particle emitter shape, and assign emittance to each vertex at a rate that makes them always appear at these locations, using a small circle texture, and the "look at camera" mode of placard presentation.

here is that cheat, done with particles:

[image]

Comment: cool，can you please share the code. I have tried the second way but there were some problem I could not solve

Comment: Which is the second way? Can you show me what you did and where you got stuck?